# Dual contouring algorithm messed up -- any ideas what could cause this (screenshot)?

Tags: c#, voxel

I've ported this Dual Contouring implementation to C#:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/dualcontouring/

Unfortunately, I think I messed up somewhere along the way.  And there's a lot of code involved, so it's hard to go through and match up the C# to the original C++ (though I will if I have to).

I know this is a long shot, but here's a screenshot of what happens when I feed in voxel data for what should be a sphere.  Any ideas where I messed up?

[image: screenshot of messed up dual contouring output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  The problem was my input data, not the actual dual contouring code.  I was passing density values into each leaf node, rather than grid signs for the corners.  I should have followed the reference in the notes linking to the documentation for PolyMender, which says this:

> is a 4-bytes integer that equals 2 ^ octree_depth. The first
>   byte of a  is either 0 (denoting an intermediate node) or 1
>   (denoting an empty node) or 2 (denoting a leaf node). After the first
>   byte, an intermediate node  contains eight  structures for
>   its eight children; an empty node  contains one byte of value 0
>   or 1 denoting if it is inside or outside; and **a leaf node contains
>   one byte whose eight bits correspond to the signs at its eight corners
>   (0 for inside and 1 for outside)**. The order of enumeration of the
>   eight children nodes in an intermediate nodeis the following
>   (expressed in coordinates  ):
>   <0,0,0>,<0,0,1>,<0,1,0>,<0,1,1>,<1,0,0>,<1,0,1>,<1,1,0>,<1,1,1>. The
>   enumeration of the eight corners in a leaf node follows the same order
>   (e.g., the lowest bit records the sign at <0,0,0>).